# Angular 2 - Run 2 subscription in the same time

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have the following code:

```
//Subscription 3: role ID to role Name
        af.database.object('/roles/'+businessRole.$value)
        .subscribe((roleData) => {
        //Subscription 4: Get user info
        af.database.object('/users/'+businessRole.$key).subscribe(user => {
```

Which contains a subscription inside a subscription.

The problem here is that the app waiting for the first one before running the second one. I want to execute both of them in one time, and get the result of each. How I can do that?

I've been using `Promise.All()` before but:

1. I would love to know how I can do that with rxjs
2. I couldn't find a way to get the result of each observable using `Promise.All()`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates two Observables that complete after 1000ms and 900ms. When you run this demo you'll see that the first one completes just a moment after the first one to prove that these we're executed in parallel.

```
let obs1 = Observable.of('HTTP Response 1').delay(1000);
let obs2 = Observable.of('HTTP Response 2').delay(900);

console.log('Start');

obs1.merge(obs2)
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val), undefined, () => console.log('Completed'));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/hzmpclxDkIhnfTYcWXd5?p=preview

This prints to console:

```
Start
HTTP Response 2
HTTP Response 1
Completed
```

If you need `forkJoin()`, then see my previous answer [Observable.forkJoin() doesn't executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303012/observable-forkjoin-doesnt-executes) :).

Comment: How do I get the output of each observable data? `val` is an array with each observable output?

Comment: @TheUnreal `merge()` operator emits values from all Observables it get as argument so the callback in `.subscribe()` will be called for every response.

Comment: It's a problem since I need to get and use the output of each, and with this `merge` method I can't determine which observable retruned each output, am I wrong? For example, I'll need to store in `user` variable the first observables data, and `role` variable for the second one.

Comment: @TheUnreal Then why don't you just simply call `af.database.object('/users').subscribe(...); af.database.object('/roles...').subscribe(...);` separately? They're both called asynchronously and won't block the execution thread.

Comment: Well I can do that but wasn't sure it's the right wa to do it. Anyway, I didn't do that because I'm using those 2 observables to create an object. I put the second observarble result object inside the first one, and create one object contains both. I have just tried to create the object using this, and it actually works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe Observable.forkJoin is exactly what you need to be using in your situation.

This is how your code would look like using forkJoin:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
this.http.get('/roles/'+businessRole.$value).map((response: Response) => res.json()),
this.http.get('/users/'+businessRole.$key).map((response: Response) => res.json())
).subscribe(data => {
  data[0] // this will contain roleData
  data[1] // this will contain user
},
error => console.log(error));
```

[This](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables) is a useful link where you can learn more about observables and how to use forkJoin.

Comment: Well I tried it in my previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303012/observable-forkjoin-doesnt-executes

Comment: Great answer :)