# Multiple requests with Observables and Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subject

I have a component that makes some http requests and send the responses to another component. Currently, I'm using Observables and Subjects, every resquest is added in the subject and returns an Observable, and then I subscribe this observable and emit its response. Can someone tell me how to send the responses only after all the requests completes?

Here is a exemple of what I am doing.

```
requestLine.next(search);

observable = requestLine.mergeMap(search => {
  return service.getSearh(search)
})

observable.subscribe(res => {
  emitter.next(res);
});
```

Tks

Comment: you probably need to chain up the subscriptions to one another, could you please post some of your code, so that I can illustrate.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this : https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RXJS Wait for all observables in an array to complete (or error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734921/rxjs-wait-for-all-observables-in-an-array-to-complete-or-error)

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: @S_developer I've added to the problem description, tks

Comment: We'd need a bit more code than this to give a meaningful answer