# How to make observable wait for the previous observable to complete

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have a list of observables that needs to invoke APIs synchronously. The APIs fails for asynchronous operation. Hence an observable needs to wait for the previous observable to complete before executing, I have written a recursive solution as shown below, is there a better way to do it.

```
 private myMethod(params) {
    let paramsCopy = params.slice();
    let param = paramsCopy.shift();
    if (param) {
     let resource: ResourceModel= param.resource;
     return resource.doPost(JSON.stringify(param.data))
                    .pipe(mergeMap(res => {return myMethod(paramsCopy)})
                    ,catchError((err) => handleError()));
    } else { 
       return //completed actions;
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: You can use the `switchMap` operator. Take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057338/8712609).

Comment: Use  `concatMap - waits for the previous Observable to complete before creating the next one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concat(observables: ...*): Observable. With this, the observable will wait for the other to complete. Please refer the link - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Answer (score 1):

```
myService.get1().pipe(
  switchMap(responseOfGet1 => myService.get2())
).subscribe(responseOfGet2 => { ... });
```

[Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)