# Make operations sequential with RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I have a service which is responsible to send and retrieve data to backed. Operations can be:
 - fetch data (all the model or part of it)
 - delete one element
 - update existing element
 - create new element

Operations can be triggered by user input. I want to make sure that one operation is done only after all the previous are finished. How can this be done with RxJS?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734921/rxjs-wait-for-all-observables-in-an-array-to-complete-or-error), but in that case new operations are not started after the old ones are finished.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RXJS Wait for all observables in an array to complete (or error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734921/rxjs-wait-for-all-observables-in-an-array-to-complete-or-error)

Comment: I think this logic of ensuring that incoming task are executed one after another in the correct order should be added to your backend not your frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using concat, which will generate a new Observable. Each time a new operation is requested, the service will have to create a new observable.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

```js
const { interval, concat} = rxjs;
const { take } = rxjs.operators;
 
let x = concat(
  interval(500).pipe(take(1)),
  interval(500).pipe(take(2)),
)
 
concat (
  x,
  interval(500).pipe(take(3)),
).subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want the [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) function, which waits for all passed Observables to complete before emitting.

Comment: It does'n not ensure that observable are done one after the other I think.